# How to create an Audio Unit without the template in Xcode 4.2?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, xcode4.2, audiounit

I have just installed Xcode 4.2, and I was about to start a new Audio Unit instrument project for OSX Lion, but in Xcode 4.2's New Project menu, there is no longer an Audio Unit Template to choose from.

Is Apple subtly telling us not to develop Audio Units anymore and if so should we all switch to VST or something? On October 12, 2011, Apple updated their Audio Unit Component Services Reference, so I don't think this is the case, which leaves the question:

How do we go about properly developing Audio Units without a template?

Any feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: "Is Apple subtly telling us not to develop Audio Units anymore and if so should we all switch to VST or something?" ... no, they're subtly telling us to stop developing for the desktop and switch over to iOS. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

logic, garageband, soundtrack pro, mainstage, wave burner, fcps, fcpx, etc. are all apple products without vst support -- only au. i'd be very surprised if they made that move at this time =)

i would guess the reason is that the templates have not been updated yet for lion.

---

first check to see if they have updated their samples or templates (some of the templates have in the past been separate downloads).

---

scan the CoreAudio list archives at apple, because it's likely that the issue has already been risen there. users have in the past provided updated templates/fixes before apple, and the CA lists have historically been a good place to find and exchange these updates.

---

still no luck?

you will probably have to create it yourself in this case:

- begin with a template from an older xcode distribution
- update it for lion or whichever os version you are targeting (if needed)
- save it as a project template

i suggest starting with a template because the number of steps required to configure an au for a build is a bit high. you have components, resources, plugin executables, ui sub-bundles.

Comment: You are very likely correct sir. I am however disappointed in Apple for constantly neglecting their Audio Unit community, but I suppose it is my fault for updating to a new version of an Apple product soon after its release.

Comment: @Mark well, it's better *than it used to be* =) as well, pro audio/music houses are slower to adopt new os versions and drop support for old ones, compared to stuff like mainstream productivity apps. i released one of the earliest au synths which had a cocoa ui -- many small/medium non-audio apps had already made the transition from carbon to cocoa by then! that was a chicken/egg problem. so, the audio industry is generally slow to adopt. not that that is a good reason for the templates to vanish, just a bit of history in case you haven't writing aus for years.

Comment: I know what you mean. I on the other hand like to be fast to adopt. Thus is my downfall I guess. I've only been developing AUs for 2 years now.

Comment: @Mark i too am a fast adopter. at the time the technology became available, 64 bit was a high priority for me. of course, the industry (e.g. popular hosts and big plugin lines) really did not catch up for a few years in that regard. just cross your fingers when a major host adds support for new feature =)

Comment: Justin is correct; the templates just haven't been updated for 10.7, and given Apple's iOS frenzy, it's unlikely to be high on their list of priorities.